# PHP file not working on my chrome browser, or in my html files

Tags: php, html, iframe

For my website, I am trying to embed stackoverflow.com and google.com, but it isn't working. So I started to work with PHP, but that didn't work. Does PHP work in html, or is it because I am using chromebook? Please help.

```
<iframe src="https://google.com" width="925" height="2400" frameborder="0" ></iframe><httpProtocol> <customHeaders> <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="*" /> </customHeaders> </httpProtocol><LocationMatch "/your_relative_path"> ProxyPass absolute_path_of_your_application/your_relative_path ProxyPassReverse absolute_path_of_your_application/your_relative_path </LocationMatch>
```

Comment: You need to have a web server to do that, try to install WAMP/MAMP.

Comment: I only use chromebook, and I can't download any extra browsers or .exe files.

Comment: you can buy some cheap hosting and you can use that to test so you won't have to install anything locally. You can't include php code in a file with the .html extension. You can combine php with html but you have to do it in a file with the extension .php

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly add most of the websites using iframe.
PHP files can't run directly on a web browser like HTML files, you have to use a server like Xampp.

Comment: So is there a way to import PHP script in HTML? Like in <script src="" lang="php">?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Embed PHP in a .html File</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php echo "Hello World" ?></h1>
</body>
</html>

you can use it like this but this will not run in an HTML file, you have to save it as a PHP file and need to use a server to interpret the code.

Comment: And since I am on chromebook, can I run the code in an iframe? If not, then I will find a server that will allow the php code :)

Comment: Using an Iframe to embed sites like google is not possible. most of the websites have restrictions to block embedding their sites in other websites.

Comment: https://google.com/webhp?igu=1 but I can't find any other way to put in google images or google docs.

Comment: Is .phtml an extension or is it built in?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers only understand html, css (for markup and display) and javascript (for logic execution on the rendered (displayed) html view). Therefore, whichever framework you may use (like php) to serve any kind of content on browser, it should eventually send the content in html format to be displayed properly. (Other content types such as - image, video, file etc. are handled differently.)

For the iframe part, as others have stated in their answers, you cannot just embed any website on the internet in your own using the iframe tag. Browsers respect many response headers sent by websites, including the `X-Frame-Options`, which, if present in the website's response with `deny` as value, instructs any browser to disallow the content from that website to be served in an `iframe`. There are many other supported values for this header, and many other such headers have been standardized under `Content security policy` concept of the web.

So, it has most likely nothing to do with your Chromebook, if you're using the normal browsers.

Comment: So I have to use a Windows 10 or a Mac to run PHP (like as a .exe file)?

Comment: That's something which you should check on PHP's supported platforms (on their website), whether it is available for Chromebook or not. But if only serving the html code is the requirement, you can simply run a temporary server using python or any other utility too. ```python -m http.server``` in shell (or cmd), then visit localhost:8000 in browser, and navigate to your html file from there.

Answer (score 0):

some website hoster don't want you to embed their sites into your own website. They can restrict this by setting [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).
There is no way you can embed their sites using iframes.

And additionally: You can't run PHP directly in HTML. Please refer to the [PHP Docs](https://php.net/)

Comment: I can't run PHP on my chromebook unless it's in a .html file. So I can't use PHP on chromebook?

Comment: @TheRealDigitalMaster You can install PHP on a Chromebook. https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9145439?hl=en first.

Comment: My family link doesn't let me be a developer. I can only make html files for now. But I can ask my parents if I can not be supervised by family link.

Comment: Also does linux include Python?